# How to correctly represent both hline and abline in a legend in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a legend in `ggplot2` for `hlines` and `ablines` using clues from other similar questions. I am close to getting what I need with the following code (and example image) but I can't seem to get rid of the extra lines crossing the legend icons.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y=mpg, col = factor(cyl))) + geom_point()
p + geom_hline(aes(lty="foo",yintercept=20)) +
  geom_hline(aes(lty="bar",yintercept=25)) +
  geom_hline(aes(lty="bar",yintercept=30)) +
  geom_abline(aes(lty = "regression", intercept = 10 , slope = 1)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name="",values=c(2,3,1))
```

[image]

This behavior in the legend only appears when I include the `abline`. Without it, both `hline` appear as intended in the legend.

What am I missing here?

**As a secondary point:** both hlines (labelled "bar" here) here use the exact same configuration, but have different values for `yintercept`. I wasn't able to draw both of them with the same command, receiving an error (`Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (32): linetype, yintercept`).

Whenever I copy&paste a command like this, it feels like I'm not doing it right. Is it possible to set two `yintercepts`, while manually defining the linetype to create a legend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use argument `show.legend` in the `geom_abline`:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = mtcars$wt, y=mtcars$mpg, col = factor(mtcars$cyl))) +
  geom_hline(aes(lty=c("foo", "bar","bar"),yintercept=c(20,25,30))) +
  geom_abline(aes(lty = "regression", intercept = 10 , slope = 1), show.legend = F) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name="",values=c(2,3,1) )
```

If you not define the data on the ggplot command you can define all the hlines in just one command:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y=mpg, col = factor(cyl))) + geom_point() +
 geom_hline(aes(lty="foo",yintercept=20)) +
  geom_hline(aes(lty="bar",yintercept=25)) +
  geom_hline(aes(lty="bar",yintercept=30)) +
  geom_abline(aes(lty = "regression", intercept = 10 , slope = 1), show.legend = F) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name="",values=c(2,3,1) )
```

Comment: Wow, I feel *silly*... Thank you for this!

About the second issue: do you have any idea on how to define both `geom_hline()` in a single statement?

Comment: @philsh For the second question, you would have not to pass the dataframe on thje ggplot command. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @philsf, you would need to pull the "yintercept = ##" part out of the aesthetic. Like `geom_hline(yintercept = c(25, 30), aes(lty = "bar")`

Comment: @NickNimchuk I believe if you do that, the labels won't appear in the legend, which was the initial intention.